# NextJS: Waiting for the data from Google Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

So, I'm trying to get data from Google Firestore and I'm using NextJS framework.

```
Index.getInitialProps = async function () {
  const db = await loadDB()
  let data = []
  db.firestore().collection('data').get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      data.push(doc.data())
      console.log(data)
    })
  })

  return {
    data
  }
}
```

So, on my "server" I get the data but in my Index component, it just remains an empty array... anyone know what I'm missing here to get the data to the component?

I'm assuming it's an await somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wondering where the missing `await` is supposed to be, there's only one place.  It only works with promises, and the `get()` returns a promise, since the query to Firestore is not immediately complete.

```
async function () {
  const db = await loadDB()
  let data = []
  const querySnapshot = await db.firestore().collection('data').get()
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    data.push(doc.data())
    console.log(data)
  })

  return {
    data
  }
})
```

Comment: Yep, that was it! I was just not connecting the dots today.